# smoothdivscroll - only scroll on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using smootdivscroll for displaying products on a website. Products all load into a large div which then scrolls left and right using the smootdivscroll script. I have setup arrows on left and right that scroll when hovered or clicked.

I want to disable the mouseover scrolling and only allow scrolling when arrows clicked.

[Actual page](http://greenlight.ie/webserver/sienaleather/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_67)

[Smoothdiv scroll demo page](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo)

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has that feature built-in. However you could probably make use of this public method : http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/publicMethods.html#move

Disable `hotSpotScrolling` in the options and bind some click event listeners to those arrows that will trigger the `move()` method.

Comment: This is a better idea but looses some of the niceness of the plugin.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Indeed, but it's either that or monkey-patching the source code to turn those mouseover/mouseout listeners into mousedown/mouseup. Either way isn't going to be elegant, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation on this, its not going to be possible without hacking the plugin. The hotspots listen for hover and click, and you cannot disable one without the other.

The place to hack away, should you choose to (not advised) is here https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll/blob/master/js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js#L195

you will need to remove all but the `mousedown` and `mouseup` listeners.

Comment: Unfortunately that just disables scrolling by both clicking and hovering.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help and ideas, below was my solution.

Firstly disable hotspots and hotspotscrolling:

```
visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "",
hotSpotScrolling: false
```

I created two links, late updated to arrow images that control the scrolling:

```
<a title="Scroll Left" href="#" onclick="MoveLeft();return false;">LEFT</a>
<a title="Scroll Right" href="#" onclick="MoveRight();return false;">RIGHT</a>
```

Use two simple functions to advance scrolling by +- 200px

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MoveRight() {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("move", 200);
    }
    function MoveLeft() {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("move", -200);
    }
</script>
```

To smooth the scrolling effect set:

```
easingAfterMouseWheelScrolling: true
```